# Buscar valores em um array com uma condição

Tags: javascript

Bom tenho um queue ( que é uma coleção de players)

```
class Queue {
  constructor() {
    this.players = [];
  }

  // addPlayers add multiple players into queue
  addPlayers(players) {

      this.players = this.players.concat(players);
  }

  // addPlayer adds a single player into queue
  addPlayer(player) {
    if(!this.players.find(p => p.id == player.id)){
      this.players.push(player);
    }
  }

  // removePlayers remove multiple players from queue
  removePlayers(players) {
    players.forEach(p => {
      this.removePlayer(p);
    });
  }

  // removePlayer removes a single player from queue
  removePlayer(player) {
    this.players = this.players.filter(p => p.id !== player.id)
  }

  // getPlayers return players that are currently on queue
  getPlayers() {
    return this.players;
  }

  searching(id) {
    const firstPLayer = this.players.find(p => p.id == id)
    const { mmr } = firstPLayer
    const secondPlayer = this.players.find((playerTwo) => playerTwo.mmr < (5 / 100) * mmr + mmr && playerTwo.mmr > mmr - ((5 / 100) * mmr) && playerTwo.id != firstPLayer.id);
    if(!secondPlayer){
      return null;
    }
    const matchedPlayers = [
      firstPLayer,
      secondPlayer
    ]
    // remove matched players from this.players
    this.removePlayers(matchedPlayers);
    // return new Match with matched players
    return matchedPlayers;
  }
}
```

e então eu preciso retirar dessa lista dois jogadores ( players ) aleatoriamente que obedeça uma condição que tenha mmr igual ou entre 5% para mais ou para menos.

Ou seja preciso de 2 players que atendam essa condição

Eu pensei em fazer isso utilizando um filter e dps um slice(0,2)
mas no meu filter eu não imagino como eu poderia filtrar os players que tenham mmr igual ou entre 5 % a mais ou a menos
Não creio que seja possível..
ALguém poderia me ajudar com isso?

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde, não sei se entendi direito mas como você precisa validar se
a mmr é maior/menor que 5%, você pode validar se é mmr < 11 que vai atender as 2 condições.